# XML Parsing painfully slow

Tags: python, xml, parsing, lxml, elementtree

I'm current parsing 4 different XML files, each around 500MB. I expect around 30'/file, but it took so long for just 1 (7 hours to be exact), and somehow loops on itself. Any ideas on how to optimize the code? I've been looking on the web for a while now and can't find an answer.

```
    import sys
    import os
    import re
    from lxml import etree
    from datetime import datetime
    import pandas as pd
    final = pd.DataFrame()
    files = os.listdir(r'.\\XML Files')
    
    def ns_cleaner(tag):
        tag = re.sub("{.\*?}","",tag)
        return tag
    
    for file in files:
        start = datetime.now()
        parser = etree.XMLParser(ns_clean=True)
        tree = etree.parse(r'.\\XML Files{}'.format(file))
        print('file parsed in {}s'.format((datetime.now()-start)))
        firstInsertFlag = False
        root = tree.getroot()
        docMes = root\[0\]
        header = docMes\[0\]
        body = docMes\[1\]
    
    # create list of dictionaries of all BusinessDocumentInstance brackets in the XML document
    filedate = header[1][0][0].text
    instances = body[0]
    
    instanceCount = len(instances.getchildren())
    
    # parsing each BusinessDocumentInstance bracket
    rowId = 0
    #for instance in instances.getchildren():
    for instance in tree.xpath('/')
        #create result dictionary to append to final df
        result = {'RowID': None}
        
        
        # initiate EntityID column first, so that it's at the correct position
        result['EntityID'] = None
        
    
        # parse common fields between documents
        result['BusinessDocument.Sequence.Number'] = int(instance[0].text)
        result['File Name'] = 'RPTROutboundResponse2514109912508'
        result['File Receive Date'] = filedate
    
        # parsing RPTRReturn/RP bracket content in respective instance
        # Note: there are 3 main brackets in RPTRReturn: RP, GA & INT. We're interested in RP only
        try:
            #Check if RPTReturn event exist or not
            instanceText = instance[1]
            if len(instanceText) >= 2:
                rptrreturn = instanceText[-1]
            else:
                print(instanceText.getchildren)
                continue
        except AttributeError as ae:
            print(ae)
        else:
            rp = rptrreturn[2]
            result['IdentifiersAustralianBusinessNumberIdentifier'] = rp[0].text
            result['OrganisationNameDetailsOrganisationalNameText'] = rp[1].text
    
            # parsing only transaction bracket in RPTRReturn/RP
            
            transaction = rp[3]
    
            result['RealEstatePropertyTransactionIdentifier'] = transaction[0].text
    
            # parsing entities in 'entities' bracket
            entities = transaction[1]
    
            # as each entity will have both commmon & uncommon fields, it's best to keep a 'base' backup 
            #           of the common fields to reset the 'result' dictionary after each loop iteration
    
            resultBase = result.copy()
    
            # as our focus is on the multiple entities in each transaction, we must keep track of them using an id variable
            entity_id = 1
    
            for entity in entities.getchildren():
                # reset 'result' dictionary to 'base'
                result = resultBase.copy()
    
                # setting the correct entityID
                result['EntityID'] = entity_id
                entity_id += 1
    
                result['IdentifiersReferenceIdentifier'] = entity[0].text
    
                # parse ReportedDetails bracket for each entity
                
                repDet = entity[2]
                for detail in repDet.getchildren():
                    result[ns_cleaner(detail.tag)] = detail.text
    
                outcome = entity[3].text
                result['ReportOutcomeText'] = outcome
    
                # only parse 'MatchedDetails' tag if ReportOutcomeText == 'Matched'
                if outcome == 'Matched':
                    try:
                        matDet = entity[4]
                    except (KeyError, AttributeError, IndexError):
                        pass
                    else:
                        for matchedResult in matDet.getchildren():
                            # examine each children tags (NonIndividual, etc...) for their content
                            for child in matchedResult.getchildren():
                                result['{}_{}'.format(ns_cleaner(matchedResult.tag),ns_cleaner(child.tag))] = child.text
                    # append result dictionary into final df
                    result['RowID'] = rowId
                    rowId += 1
                    final = final.append(result, ignore_index=True)
            
        final.to_csv(r'./test.csv', index = False)     
        percentage = round((rowId/instanceCount) * 100,2)
        if percentage % 10 == 0 and percentage != 0:
            sys.stdout.write('\r')
            sys.stdout.write('Finished {}% of {} instances at {}\n'.format(percentage,instanceCount, datetime.now()))
            sys.stdout.flush()
        if rowId == instanceCount:
            break
        
    sys.stdout.write('Done with file {}\n'.format(file))
    sys.stdout.write('************************\n')
```

The past version of the code uses XMLtoDict, which proves to be way too slow. I opt for LXML.etree (thought of objectify to make code conversion easier but etree seems to be a little faster). I've looked over articles on the web on how to make it parse faster, but I don't understand a thing.

Comment: Please, take some time to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You should add a minimum working sample of the XML file to make the question reproducible.

Comment: @LMC I'll take note and modify. This is my first time posting seriously, so I made a mistake. Thank you for the kind suggestion.

Comment: How looks like the xml structure and what kind of information are you interested in?